# How to correct for: TypeError: '_FlagValues' object is not subscriptable while retraining mobilenet model

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, flags

I am trying to retrain a mobilenet model using -

```
!python tensorflow/hubmaster/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--tfhub_module=https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/2
```

But am getting the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "tensorflow/tensorflow/hub-master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1313, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/tensorflow/hub-master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 998, in main
    module_spec = hub.load_module_spec(FLAGS.tfhub_module)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module.py", line 57, in load_module_spec
    path = registry.resolver(path)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/registry.py", line 42, in __call__
    return impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/compressed_module_resolver.py", line 77, in __call__
    module_dir = _module_dir(handle)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/compressed_module_resolver.py", line 45, in _module_dir
    cache_dir = resolver.tfhub_cache_dir(use_temp=True)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/resolver.py", line 68, in tfhub_cache_dir
    os.getenv(_TFHUB_CACHE_DIR, "") or FLAGS["tfhub_cache_dir"].value or

TypeError: '_FlagValues' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried changing `os.getenv(_TFHUB_CACHE_DIR, "")` to `os.getenv(TFHUB_CACHE_DIR, "")` in `resolver.py` (second last line of error) as shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/127), but am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an older version of Tensorflow. I was initially using Tensorflow 1.4, on upgrading to Tensorflow 1.9 I didn't get this error